# Modify an object's variable value after submiting form in Angular2

Tags: forms, angular

I'm trying to modify an object latitude and longitude values after I submit the form because after submiting it I need to pass a geocode function to it's address.

I'm using this function to modify the lat and lng:

```
setLanLon(address : string){
this.getLatLon(address).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.foo.lat= data.lat();
                this.foo.lng= data.lng();
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
}
```

And the function that is called on the form submit and in which I'm calling the function that modifies the values is this one:

```
edit() {
    this.setLanLon(this.foo.address);
    this.service.update(this.foo)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
}
```

But the lat and lng values that I receive in the service are the original values not the ones I modify with my function. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's up with `data.lat()` and `data.lng()`, shouldn't it be just `data.lat` and `data.lng`, or how does your response look like? And your `update`-method is fired before `foo` has been manipulated. Try executing the method after setting the new values: `.... this.foo.lng= data.lng; this.service.update(this.foo)....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.service.update(this.foo)
```

is executed before the

```
this.setLanLon(this.foo.address);
```

has finished executing and setting the new values for `foo`, therefore the old values are sent.

Secondly, check what response you are actually getting from `setLanLon` so you have the correct values set.

So try this:

```
edit() {
  this.setLanLon(this.foo.address);
}

setLanLon(address : string){
  this.getLatLon(address).subscribe(
     data => {
        this.foo.lat= // check response what to assign
        this.foo.lng= // check response what to assign
        this.service.update(this.foo)
          .subscribe(
             data => {
               this.router.navigate(['/home']);
             },
             error => {
               console.log(error);
            });
     },
     error => {
        console.log(error);
     });
}
```

Comment: The problem was as u said that my update method was fired before updating the values i changed it like u said and now it works. The response from getLanLon was fine. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Okay great. Glad I could help! :) Happy coding!